# How do I create and write in a json file object in Python, without having to store it locally?

Tags: python, json, file, methods, python-requests

I want to store data in a JSON file as an object in Python without having to store it locally, but I have not found any way of doing this! Currently, I create a file locally like so:

```
open(local_file_name + '.json', 'wb').write(file.content)
```

and then I proceed to use it for various functions. The problem, however, is that I create multiple of these files, so many in fact that it would simply be easier for me if I could somehow make them objects instead. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do u mean `I create multiple of these files`?

Comment: create it once and then don't write, but append; instead of `"wb"` use `"a+"` after the first wb

Comment: `it would simply be easier for me if I could somehow make them objects instead`... then why don't you?

Comment: Use the ```io``` module https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/io.html

Comment: @SerialLazer Basically I download a bunch of JSON files and then create files in which i store their data! But I want to somehow send the data and upload it as a file in Azure directly without having to store a file locally on my computer.

Comment: @Petronella Okay, is there no option where I do not have to create a file locally?

Comment: @Kraay89 That is what I want to do, but I do not know how to do this! I have looked all over it seems but I still haven't figured it out

Comment: @PhilippSelenium I will check it out

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. You can always have an in-memory object, say a dictionary, even a string I supose, the size depends on your PC and Python settings. You can even create your own object, i.e. define a class. The point is that once you finish the program, the object is not persisted.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my code lacked one very important line of code: file.close()
Here is my code. Perhaps the data is stored locally for some time, but there is no JSON file created within the directory.

```
local_path = os.getcwd()

local_file_name = 'example.json'
f = open(local_file_name, 'wb')
f.write(file.content)
f.close()

upload_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)
```

Now I can upload the file object!